# Pruning (limiting) partitions in BigQuery not working as expected

Tags: google-bigquery

Given a table:

[image: 6ilecJ1]

partitioned by `_date`:

[image: WYxPb5Y]

with quite an even distribution of rows across partitions:

[image: Q8DOY0M]

When trying to prune (limit) the partitions in a query, the amount of processed bytes is quite high:

[image: ieSkZsI]

However, when I copy the table over into a new one:

```sql
CREATE TABLE
  `analytics-310706.domain_events_tables_repartitioned.domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482`
PARTITION BY
  _date AS
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `analytics-310706.domain_events_tables.domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482`
```

[image: Y1mN93Q]

And then issue the same query, the number of bytes processed is orders of magnitude lower:

[image: nSZBW1a]

What's wrong with the original table? ([The partition statistics look ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPmar.png). And I don't see the cause in [the execution details of the original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAgJL.png).) Why do we need to spend 166 MB for the query on it, while the same query only costs 0.75 MB on the copied table?

(It's not just the estimation that differs so much, but also [the number of actually processed bytes](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/8333d87c6baf42316a861fd75cd42014).)

Comment: It looks weird. The only main difference btw the 2 tables seems to be the Streaming Buffer. In the original one you are still streaming data into it... It has to be related to that somehow, but I'm not 100% sure why. It won't resolve anything but maybe you can check double check it if you also stream data into the 2nd table and see what it happens.

Comment: @Alvaro Thanks for the idea. Starting around half an hour ago, I'm now [streaming into this copied table too](https://i.imgur.com/BOHkcOB.png), but the query dry run still tells `This query will process 750.5 KiB when run.`

Comment: Try to compare number of partitions `SELECT * FROM mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS WHERE table_name = 'partitionedtable'` - [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#partitions_view)

Comment: @TobiasHermann We ruled out that option too. Open question.. Is it possible that somehow BQ repartition the data in a better/performant way after a select * ? I know this is happening in Cluster tables, but I didn't expect that in partitioned tables.

Comment: @SergeyGeron Thanks! The result is [here](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/ea773c4f468acec5d4f42151769124ea). In the problematic original table, there are many rows in the `__STREAMING_UNPARTITIONED__` partition. According to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaming_into_partitioned_tables), `When there's enough unpartitioned data, BigQuery partitions the data into the correct partition`. I wonder if I can force this somehow (or find out what "enough" means). (I'd like to avoid using a partition decorator or batch jobs.)

Comment: After having looked [the `__STREAMING_UNPARTITIONED__` data for all our ~ 300 tables](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/aff0344eba50f13598ceaec6e8559631), it seems, the limit is around 5 GiB. So if I understand correctly, that would mean, once `__STREAMING_UNPARTITIONED__` exceeds this limit, the data in it is put into the partitions. From a financial point of view, that means, the additional cost for filtering the not-yet-partitioned data also should not grow too big, also not for tables much larger than the one I've used as an example here. Does this make sense to you guys? :-)

Comment: To limit the partitions that are scanned in a query, use a constant expression in your filter. If you use dynamic expressions in your query filter, BigQuery must scan all of the partitions. You can use the _PARTITIONTIME and _PARTITIONDATE pseudo columns to limit the number of partitions scanned during a query. This is also referred to as pruning partitions.  In general, partition pruning helps reduce query cost when the filters consist of constant expressions, which can be evaluated at the outset of the query.

Comment: @RaulSaucedo Thanks, but yes, I know that. In the case shown, I'm using a constant expression (not a dynamic) expression in my query filter.

Comment: @TobiasHermann Your explanation makes sense to me. That can explain why after copying the table, the query processes less MB. It would be nice to report that to Google because it is a quite 'interesting' behaviour. From now on, if I'll stream to a table for long time, I wont consume that one. Instead I'll create a cron job to copy the full table every X amount of time to a different one, and consume it.

Comment: @Alvaro Thanks! I've summarized our findings in an answer. :-) I don't know if reporting to Google makes sense because from [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaming_into_partitioned_tables) it seems to be intended behavior.

Comment: Hi @YunZhang! Could you please take a look at this question?

Comment: @TobiasHermann Thanks for summarized this. It was a nice lesson learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments of Alvaro and Sergey Geron, we concluded the following:

The original (streamed-into) table has data in the `__STREAMING_UNPARTITIONED__` partition, while the copied table has not:

```sql
SELECT * FROM domain_events_tables.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS WHERE table_name = "domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482" ORDER BY partition_id
```

```
+------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+--------------+
|  table_catalog   |     table_schema     |               table_name               |        partition_id         | total_rows | total_logical_bytes | total_billable_bytes | last_modified_time  | storage_tier |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+--------------+
...
| analytics-310706 | domain_events_tables | domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482 | 20211120                    |      64710 |            12834643 |             12834643 | 2021-11-21 12:20:38 | ACTIVE       |
| analytics-310706 | domain_events_tables | domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482 | 20211121                    |      69645 |            13815947 |             13815947 | 2021-11-22 11:38:08 | ACTIVE       |
| analytics-310706 | domain_events_tables | domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482 | 20211122                    |      63150 |            12525886 |             12525886 | 2021-11-23 10:44:59 | ACTIVE       |
| analytics-310706 | domain_events_tables | domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482 | 20211123                    |      16329 |             3241645 |              3241645 | 2021-11-23 10:44:59 | ACTIVE       |
| analytics-310706 | domain_events_tables | domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482 | __STREAMING_UNPARTITIONED__ |   21663333 |          4289424844 |           4289424844 | 2021-11-09 09:33:09 | ACTIVE       |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM domain_events_tables_repartitioned.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS WHERE table_name = "domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482" ORDER BY partition_id
```

```
+------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+--------------+
|  table_catalog   |     table_schema     |               table_name               |        partition_id         | total_rows | total_logical_bytes | total_billable_bytes | last_modified_time  | storage_tier |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+--------------+
...
| analytics-310706 | domain_events_tables_repartitioned | domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482 | 20211118     |      63235 |            12539401 |             12539401 | 2021-11-20 14:15:02 | ACTIVE       |
| analytics-310706 | domain_events_tables_repartitioned | domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482 | 20211119     |      60737 |            12044526 |             12044526 | 2021-11-20 14:15:02 | ACTIVE       |
| analytics-310706 | domain_events_tables_repartitioned | domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482 | 20211120     |      29177 |             5784204 |              5784204 | 2021-11-20 14:15:02 | ACTIVE       |
| analytics-310706 | domain_events_tables_repartitioned | domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482 | 20211122     |         91 |               18122 |                18122 | 2021-11-23 10:53:56 | ACTIVE       |
| analytics-310706 | domain_events_tables_repartitioned | domain_user_UserRegistered__1838592482 | 20211123     |       2531 |              501233 |               501233 | 2021-11-23 10:53:56 | ACTIVE       |
+------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

When doing the query (with the constant filter expression on the partition column), on the copied table only the matching partition needs to be scanned by the BigQuery engine, while on the original table, the matching partition *and* all rows in the `__STREAMING_UNPARTITIONED__` need to be scanned.

This causes the difference.

---

To find out the maximum cost penalty one can be hit by due to streaming into a table, I checked [the number of bytes in the `__STREAMING_UNPARTITIONED__` partition of all our ~ 300 tables](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/aff0344eba50f13598ceaec6e8559631), and it seems, BigQuery never leaves more than 5 GiB in the `__STREAMING_UNPARTITIONED__` before moving the rows into the appropriate partitions. That means, from a financial point of view, the additional cost for filtering the not-yet-partitioned data should not grow too big (no matter the overall table size, max 5 GiB, usually much less because only one column is read for filtering).

In retrospect, this also matches what is described in the [BigQuery Streaming Docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaming_into_partitioned_tables):

> When there's enough unpartitioned data, BigQuery automatically repartitions the data, placing it into the appropriate partition.